# How to solve two 2 variable quadratics using system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

Given
$\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcr}
{\displaystyle\left(x + 2\right)^{2}} & {\displaystyle +} &
{\displaystyle\left(y - 2\right)^{2}} & {\displaystyle = } &
{\displaystyle 9}
\\[1mm]
{\displaystyle\left(x - 2\right)^{2}} & {\displaystyle +} &
{\displaystyle\left(y + 2\right)^{2}} & {\displaystyle = } &
{\displaystyle 25}
\end{array}\right.
$ 

Find the two solutions for $\left(x,y\right)$.
How do I do this ?.

Comment: With geometry, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Write 
$$x^2+y^2+4x-4y=1$$
$$x^2+y^2-4x+4y=17$$
and compute eqn2-eqn1:
so $$-8x+8y=16$$
Can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Difference of two terms gives: $8x-8y=-16\iff x=y-2$. By substitution $(x+2)^2+x^2=9$. Now expand and solve for x.